# Two v-data-tables, second table has v-select that uses the data from the first table in the dropdown. Somehow is bound to newest data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have two v-data-tables that are being rendered in a component. The first one is imported from another file as the matching-game-crud-table. This is the answer table. This first table manipulates information for the answerObject array, which is also used in the second tables to populate the v-select dropdown element. The first table (answer table) is set up like this below. Its items are updating the answerObjects on the main file.

```
    <template>
        <v-container>
            <v-data-table
                :headers="tableHeaders"
                :items="items"
                class="elevation-1"
            >
            <template #[`item.display`]="{item}">
                <v-text-field
                            v-model="item.display"
                            :hide-details="true"
                            dense
                            outlined
                            :autofocus="true"
                            label="Display"
                        >

                            <!-- <v-icon v-if="header.draggable" slot="prepend"
                                >mdi-drag-vertical</v-icon
                            > -->
                </v-text-field>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
    components: { draggable },
    props: {
        headers: { type: Array, required: true, default: [] },
        defaultItem: { type: Object, required: true, default: {} },
        allowDrag: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
        useModal: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
        data: { type: Array, required: true, default: [] },
    },
    data: () => ({
        dialog: false,
        dialogDelete: false,
        items: [],
        editedIndex: -1,
        editedItem: {},
    }),
    computed: {
        tableHeaders() {
            let new_headers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.headers))
            new_headers.push({
                text: 'Actions',
                value: 'actions',
                sortable: false,
            })
            return new_headers
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.items = _.cloneDeep(this.data)
        this.editedItem = _.cloneDeep(this.defaultItem)
    },
    created() {},
    methods: {
        addNew() {
            console.log('add new')
            const addObj = _.cloneDeep(this.defaultItem)
            addObj.id = this.items.length + 1
            this.items.push(addObj)
            this.$emit('input', this.items)
        },
    },
}
```

The main page is set up like this. This is the page where you can see the second v-data-table with the v-select that is using the answerObjects array. The matching-game-crud-table is the file that utilizes the first table. There is a watch set up for the answerObject on the main file so that it is updated with the newest empty answer object from the matching-game-crud-table component.

```
 <matching-game-crud-table
                            :headers="headers"
                            :default-item="default_item"
                            :data="answerObjects"
                            allow-drag
                            v-model="answerObjects"
 ></matching-game-crud-table>
 <v-data-table
     :headers="promptHeaders"
     :items="prompts"
     class="elevation-1"
 >
    <template #[`item.answer`]="{item, index}">
        <v-select
           :hide-details="true"
           v-model="item.answer"   
           :items="answerObjects"
           item-text="display"
           item-value="display"
           outlined
           dense
           label="Choose an answer value"
           @input="change($event, true)"
        ></v-select>
    </template>                       
 </v-data-table>
<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
import _ from 'lodash'
import MatchingGameCrudTable from '../../MatchingGameCrudTable.vue'

export default {
    name: 'MatchingGame',
    components: {  MatchingGameCrudTable, draggable },
    props: {
        value: { type: String, required: true },
        data: { type: Object, required: true },
    },
    watch: {
        answerObjects(newData, oldData) {
            console.log(newData)
            this.items = [newData]
            console.log(this.items)
            // this.mainBucket = this.setMainBucket()
        },
    },
   data(){
     return{
       default_item: {
            id: 0,
            display: '',
            feedback: '',
        },
       prompts: [],
       answerObjects: [],
       items: [],
     }
   }
</script>
```

The issue that seems to be happening is that if I add a new Answer to the answer table, then the addNew function is called and updates the answerObjects array with an empty answer object. For some reason if I also have an empty prompt object on the second table that has not been filled in yet, so the prompt.answer key is "". Then the v-select will take on the empty answer objects as the prompts answer. So as I fill in an answer in the empty answer object. The prompt answer is linked and is updated along with it. But the prompt answer is still "", it is just updating the v-select dropdown. I want the v-select to remain unchosen. And then the dropdown should populate with the answer value, but the user should be manually selecting it. I am unsure of why this link is occuring

Comment: What solved the issue was changing the default object that the prompts table was intialized with. The default answer and default prompt both intilized with "" so I had to change one to initlize with null and then the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest u fetch data from a central state like vuex, if the v-select is triggered on the first table it alters the state, then the second table uses the altered state